# How to use '--fix' to modify with Vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I made some project by vue-cli 3.
So there is a lint in scripts of Package.json
And it makes so much error with eslint.
I want to use '--fix' to solve this automatically.
But where and how should I use '--fix' in commnad?

Comment: The `lint` npm script (without any flags) should automatically fix any lint errors. No need to specify `--fix`; just run `npm run lint`. What errors are you seeing (and for which eslint rules)? And what command did you try?

Answer (score 31):

`./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service lint --fix` seems to work

Comment: Is it possible to make `vue-cli-service serve` use --fix for lint?

Comment: @Sebi you can write sth like `start: vue-cli-service lint --fix && vue-cli-service serve` under `script` section in `package.json`. Then `serve` will be execute only if `lint` pass. But this wouldn't work in HMR so I suppose it is not your goal.

In second hand I don't see any reason why you want to execute `lint --fix` as often?, Better way will be add some hooks and do list magic before every commit (read mode: `husky`, `lint-staged`)

Comment: just for informational purposes, `yarn` appends cli args to the npm script it runs. so `yarn lint --fix` will run it with the `fix` flag.

Comment: I modified the pre-commit hook to lint --fix. I don't see an issue with this, yet.

Answer (score 11):

Try with `npm run lint -- --fix`

Answer (score 7):

Just found this one, seems to work, autofixing as you go. Add to your vue.config.js

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rule('eslint').use('eslint-loader').options({
      fix: true
    })
 }
```

Comment: This worked for me with the vue-cli dev server, aka `vue-cli-service serve`

Comment: `eslint-loader` has been deprecated . Please use `eslint-webpack-plugin`.
[check here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add another npm script, just use `npx vue-cli-service lint --fix`

Comment: Bro can I ask you how does that one work? Im new to vue and I just did this command because I had a comma error message and it fixed it automatically can you explain to me is that command going to fix all errors related to the missing characters or something like this?

Comment: this command will use `eslint --fix` trying to fix any eslint flaws.